# What are the python builtin __exit__ argument types?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, with-statement, traceback

Classes have a defineable function `__exit__` that allows implementation of a context manager.

It takes the required arguments:

```
def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
```

but I cannot find a definitive definition of what those arguments are and their types.

Here's my best guess of what they are and why, but I'm not entirely sure:

```
def __exit__(self, exc_type: Exception, exc_val: TracebackException, exc_tb: TracebackType):
```

### exc_type

Python defines a `TracebackException` class that accepts an `exc_type` argument which is used contextually in the constructor within [`issubclass`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/traceback.py#L516) with `SyntaxError`, which infers that `exc_type` is indeed some sort of `Exception`, which `SyntaxError` inherits from.

### exc_val

Also, in that `TracebackException` class is an `exc_value` argument that matches up to our `exc_val` which seems to have various attributes like `__cause__`, `__context__`, and other attributes that are all defined in `TracebackType` itself. This makes me think that the parameter is itself an instance of `TracebackException`.

### exc_tb

Python defines a [walk_tb](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/traceback.py#L305) function that uses `exc_tb` as an argument (manually traced from [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html)), and this object appears to have `tb_frame`, `tb_lineno`, and `tb_next` attributes which can be traced back to a `TracebackType` class in the [`typeshed`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/types.pyi#L235) library.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`exc_type` is the exception's class.  `exc_val` is the exception instance.  `exc_tb` is a traceback object, of which there is a reference in [`types.TracebackType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.TracebackType).

In general it should be the case that

- `type(exc_val) is exc_type`
- `exc_val.__traceback__ is exc_tb`

Note that `__exit__` is still invoked when there was no exception raised by the code under a context manager, and the args will be `(None, None, None)` so all three arguments should be annotated *optional*.

Then a correct annotation for it should look something like this:

```
def __exit__(self, exctype: Optional[Type[BaseException]],
             excinst: Optional[BaseException],
             exctb: Optional[TracebackType]) -> bool: ...
```

You might wonder why this API has three arguments when two of them can be trivially determined from the exception instance itself. But it wasn't always that way, in older versions of Python you could raise strings as exceptions, and the exception's `__traceback__` attribute wasn't there [until Python 2.5](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0344/). And you can still raise old-style classes as exceptions in Python 2.7 (!)

Comment: From where do we import TrackbackType?

Comment: @Mentos1386 Import it from the `types` module, not to be confused with the `typing` module.

Comment: Should the return type annotation of __exit__ be `Optional[bool]`? https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/#id38

Comment: @Laurenz  typeshed used bool https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/095464874accef1cc5303f325ccabe88756bcd8b/stdlib/2and3/contextlib.pyi#L70  I guess there’s no practical difference with returning None instead of False, but it just works because of duck typing.

Comment: If you don't want to handle the exception then  `def __exit__(self, *exc: List[Any]) -> None:` seems to do the job (Mypy doesn't complain any more).

Answer (score 10):

In [mypy issue 4885](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4885), Jelle Zijlstra provides the standard signature for `__exit__`.

Adapted to your argument names and the appropriate imports:

```py
from typing import Optional, Type
from types import TracebackType

def __exit__(
    self,
    exc_type: Optional[Type[BaseException]],
    exc_val: Optional[BaseException],
    exc_tb: Optional[TracebackType],
) -> bool:
   ...
```

You should return `True` from `__exit__` if you want to suppress an exception raised in the context and `False` in all other cases.

Comment: Isn't this just a duplicate of [wim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58808179/8075540)?